# How to improve or remove sftp hard code password camel code

Tags: passwords, apache-camel, sftp

I have the following code:-

```
    public class FtpRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            try{
                from("file:c:/temp/input/")
                        .streamCaching()
                        .to("sftp://sftpuser@192.168.10.54:/sftpuser/?password=dev&passiveMode=true");
            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.printf("ex: "+ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

There I have sftp password "dev" in the code. That is ugly. How can I remove it and set it in a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at using SSH public/private keys? The camel sftp component has a number of options to allow it.

Comment: No, I didn't. But I don't know how to do it. Can you pls suggest how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have a look at you sftp server's documentation for how to setup access using SSH keys. You'll need to generate a key pair if you don't already have one (e.g. with ssh-keygen) then put the public key on the sftp server. Don't use a pass phrase. If you do you'll have to add that to the camel route, so it'll look just as ugly.
2. Check you can do a transfer with an ftp client using your private key. i.e. test the keys before trying to use them with camel.
3. Change your route to use the private key

   ```
   from("file:c:/temp/input/")
       .streamCaching()
       .to("sftp://sftpuser@192.168.10.54:/sftpuser/?privateKeyFile=path-to-private-key-file&passiveMode=true");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have much knowledge of ssh public/private key. I generated new key those are located in .ssh/id_rsa and .ssh/id_rsa.pub. I am confused exactly where to put the public key in the sftp server. In the sftp server is mint linux. There are several users. Should I put it in the sftp user location as it is /home/sftpuser/.ssh/? There is already a id_rsa.pub. Should I replace it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sftp server in mint linux. As I said, you'll need to refer to the documentation to work this bit out. There are sure to be guides online too if you do a bit of searching.